# Where is trackpad config in Lubuntu 17.10?

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, synaptics, openbox, libinput

I've been working on this issue for a week! Macbook Air 1.1

I'm simply trying to turn off trackpad while typing, and reduce sensitivity. Lubuntu has none of these options in GUI.

xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 05ac:820b                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ bcm5974                                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 05ac:820a                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Synclient:

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = -3960
    RightEdge               = 4478
    TopEdge                 = 337
    BottomEdge              = 5311
    FingerLow               = 70
    FingerHigh              = 75
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 519
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 283
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 236
    HorizScrollDelta        = 236
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0169492
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 40
    VertHysteresis          = 23
    ClickPad                = 0
```

When I input the often suggested

```
syndaemon -i 0.5 -t -K -R
```

It does seem to have an effect, however there is no return of the cursor in the window. Perhaps this is normal. I can't use that terminal window further, which seems odd.

I do have a 50-Synaptics.conf file copied into the suitable folder, yet I read libinput is replacing Synaptics?

Further confusion is Openbox and Lubuntu documentation which suggests I should  be editing

```
~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

I find no documentation of all the options relative to touchpads in the above file.

I also find suggestions I should be inputing synclient parameters to

```
Edit ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

This file exists without content.

Is Synaptics controlling the bcm5974 driver (specific to my hardware)?

Should I replace Synaptics with Libinput or xf86-input-mtrack, and would they be interacting with the bcm5974 in the same way?

How can I determine which touchpad options in man synaptics/libinput my hardware supports?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know if this is documented well enough anywhere but in English where it says keyboard and mouse or lxinput to launch it from the command line adds accelartion from touch and trackpads as well.

Editing ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml is if you want to make a keyboard shortcut to function like a hardware switch to turn o ff the trackpad for example you have a usb mouse you plug in and when typing don't want to have the touchpad on.

`synclient touchpadoff=1` is the command for turning the touchpad off in software. while synclient `touchpadoff=0` will turn it on.

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer. It seems there are layers of drivers LOL. I don't really want a switch, I just want it to be disabled while typing, and to make it less sensitive. However, maybe lubuntu-rc.xml is the right place. I'm trying to understand the relationship of that file to synclient, and the synaptics config files.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I replace Synaptics with Libinput

probably

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/palm_detection.html#disable-while-typing

> libinput automatically disables the touchpad for a timeout after a key press

cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
Driver "libinput"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Option "Tapping" "on"
Option "ScrollMethod" "edge"
#Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
#Option "AccelProfile" "flat"
#Option "AccelSpeed" "0.5"
```